# Bad Y value -134.16105 is not in boundary Rect(minX=-180.0,maxX=180.0,minY=-90.0,maxY=90.0)

Tags: lucene, shapes, spatial

I used Spatial4j, JTs and Lucene index to do this and some of the code is below where it is failing.

```
Shape pointShape = spatialContext.makePoint(latitude, longitude); 
for (IndexableField f : spatialStrategy.createIndexableFields(pointShape)) 
  { doc.add(f); }
```

It is able to index the rows from my data file but it is failing for some rows and the exception is:

> Bad Y value -134.16105 is not in boundary Rect(minX=-180.0,maxX=180.0,minY=-90.0,maxY=90.0)

Comment: Hard to know without seeing some data.

Comment: I am trying to index the lat long pair as [-134.16105 , 57.61806 ]  but it is not allowed to do that. But, i have converted to radians then it allowed me to index this point(lat long pair). Is that something need to be indexed always with radians? And also while searching the points from index it worked only after converting the input points into radians.

Comment: I think you have lat and l'on the wrong way round. It is typically lon/lat in geospatial, ie,  X,  y. Definitely not radians.

Comment: try to exchange the position of two params, like [57.61806, -134.16105]